# Stabilizing a lightweight (empty) ship

Tags: torque, moment-of-inertia, buoyancy, stability

Is it possible to stabilize an empty ship on high ocean waves with weights on long structures free to open up like wings by rotation on two vertical axis attached to the body of the ship simmilar to a man walking on a rope with a long bar which is more massive at the ends,ofcourse not that long in proportion to make problems to other ships and only in use on not crawded parts of the ocean?Is it already in use in some cases?

Comment: floats work better, they're called outriggers

Comment: Outriggers would not be suitable for ocean-going ships. The stress on the arms would break them off in heavy seas. If you retract them when the seas are rough that  defeats the purpose of having them because that's when they're needed most. Much better to use the weight as ballast to lower the COM of the ship.

Answer (score 1):

Ocean-going ships that are empty of cargo are stabilized by filling the holds partially with water; weight added in this manner is referred to as *ballast*.